# Get Records From Array Based On Value

Tags: php, arrays, ldap

Bottom line, I have a huge multidimensional array returned by *ldap_get_entries* that I am trying to parse into different groups based on the location attribute.

In PowerShell I could do something like:

```
$location1 = Get-ADUser -Filter * | ? {?_.l -eq "test_location"}
```

What I am currently doing within PHP (as far as my brain will let me go) is something like:

```
Foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (isset($record['l'])) {
        switch ($record['l'][0]) {
            case "test_location1":
                $location1[] = $record;
                continue 2;
            case "test_location2":
                $location2[] = $record;
                continue 2;             
        }
    }
}
```

I then use a *foreach* loop (alternative syntax) against an array of location variables ($location1, $location2), that I used the above method, to sort records into their appropriate location variable. In this way, I build an HTML table grouping each locations records together. I build a new table for each location with some HTML code in between each group, so I don't believe sorting the ldap results by location will work, as it would output one large table.

Is there any way to specify a WHERE clause in PHP? So that I can assign all records in an array with a matching key value to variable1 and all records in an array with a different matching key value to variable2.

I am assuming I am tackling this in an amateur scripting way.. If there is an easier way to accomplish this task (maybe skipping the assign records to variables part), or any sort of "best practice" I am missing here, I am up for learning it.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question you want something like this:

```
$recordsSorted = array();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (! isset($record['l'])) {
        continue;
    }

    $recordsSorted[$records['l'][0]][] = $record;
}

ksort($recordsSorted);

foreach($recordsSorted as $location => $records) {
    usort($records, function($a, $b){
        return strnatcasecmp($a['uid'][0], $b['uid'][0]);
    });
    echo '<h1>$location</h1><ul>';
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        echo '<li>' . $record['dn'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This will first put the first entry to the location-attribute of an entry as key of an array. That key can then be used to sort the array.

To output the content then it iterates over the new array and sorts the content - in this case using the first value of the uid-attribute (change the `uid` to whatever attribute you need). This sorted content is then output to HTML.

the first array `$recordsSorted` might look somewhat like this:

```
array(
    'London' => array(
        array(<entry from the LDAP>),
        array(<another entry from LDAP>),
    ),
    'Paris' => array(
        array(<a further entry from the LDAP>),
    ),
    'Berlin' => array(
        array(<and even another entry from the LDAP>),
    ),
);
```

The result would then look somewhat like this:

```
<h1>Berlin</h1>
<ul>
<li>[UID of and even another entry from the LDAP]</li>    
</ul>
<h1>London</h1>
<ul>
<li>[UID of another entry from LDAP]</li>
<li>[UID of entry from the LDAP]</li>    
</ul>
<h1>Paris</h1>
<ul>
<li>[UID of a further entry from the LDAP]</li>    
</ul>
```

Does that look like it could help you?

Comment: It looks like we're onto something here. I will have to think over these concepts, and see if I can get them to work for my situation.

Comment: Can you explain in lamest terms the difference between foreach($records as $record) and foreach($recordsSorted as $location => $records). Coming from Powershell, I'm not sure I understand the difference between these two foreach structures.

Comment: The former assigns each item of the array $records to the variable $record. The later does the same, but also assigns the array-key of the entry (which in this case is the value of the ```l```-attribute) to the variable $location. For more infos on PHPs associative array have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php